# Join multiple tables, keeping NULLs

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 4 tables `user`, `posts`, `follows`, `notifications`. The `posts` table has a field called `privacy` in which a value of 1 means "anyone can see" and 2 means "only friends can see".

My `notifications` table looks like this:

```
id user_id tonotify_id notification post_id
1  2       3           ---          1
2  3       2           ---          2
3  2       4           ---          3
```

And my `follows` table looks like this:

```
id user_id tofollow_id status fstatus
1  1       2           1      1
2  1       3           1      1
```

The field `fstatus` value of 1 means that they are also friends.

Now I am trying to get all notifications sent out by people who a certain user is following (lets say a user with id 1). Assuming 1 is following user 2 and 3, I need to get all notifications from the above table. However, before this I need to make sure that the post (posted by the users in the `tonotify_id` column) is available. That is, I need to check the privacy setting. I have the following code:

```
SELECT
  u.username AS sender,
  ux.username AS receiver,
  p.id
FROM notifications n
JOIN follows f ON (n.user_id = f.tofollow_id)
JOIN follows fr ON (n.tonotify_id = fr.tofollow_id)
JOIN user u ON (u.id = n.user_id)
JOIN user ux ON (ux.id = n.tonotify_id)
LEFT JOIN posts p ON (n.posts_id = p.id)
WHERE f.user_id = 1
  AND fr.user_id = 1
  AND f.status = 1
  AND p.privacy = 1 OR (p.privacy = 2 AND fr.fstatus = 1)
ORDER BY n.id DESC
```

It seems to be working except for one glitch. Since user 1 is not following user 4 all notifications aimed at 4, even if the posts are public don't show up. This my guess has to do with `JOIN follows fr ON (n.tonotify_id = fr.tofollow_id)` because, since the user 1 hasn't followed 4, there are no rows matching this join. Any suggestions to solving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I did try [the outer join], but the output is the same.

When you use an outer join, and then use one of the "outer" columns in an equality check in the `WHERE` clause, you convert your outer join to an inner join. This is because your condition that checks post's privacy requires the post to be there:

```
AND p.privacy = 1 OR (p.privacy = 2 AND fr.fstatus = 1)
```

When an outer join is about to produce a row that corresponds to a notification without a post, it would check the above condition. Since the post is not there, `p.privacy` would evaluate to `NULL`, "contaminating" both sides of the `OR`, and eventually making the whole condition evaluate to `false`.

Moving this condition into the `ON` condition of the join will fix the problem:

```
SELECT
  u.username AS sender,
  ux.username AS receiver,
  p.id
FROM notifications n
JOIN follows f ON (n.user_id = f.tofollow_id)
JOIN follows fr ON (n.tonotify_id = fr.tofollow_id)
JOIN user u ON (u.id = n.user_id)
JOIN user ux ON (ux.id = n.tonotify_id)
LEFT JOIN posts p ON (n.posts_id = p.id)
                 AND (p.privacy = 1 OR (p.privacy = 2 AND fr.fstatus = 1))
WHERE f.user_id = 1
  AND fr.user_id = 1
  AND f.status = 1
ORDER BY n.id DESC
```

Another way to fix this would be adding an `IS NULL` condition to your `OR`, like this:

```
SELECT
  u.username AS sender,
  ux.username AS receiver,
  p.id
FROM notifications n
JOIN follows f ON (n.user_id = f.tofollow_id)
JOIN follows fr ON (n.tonotify_id = fr.tofollow_id)
JOIN user u ON (u.id = n.user_id)
JOIN user ux ON (ux.id = n.tonotify_id)
LEFT JOIN posts p ON (n.posts_id = p.id)
WHERE f.user_id = 1
  AND fr.user_id = 1
  AND f.status = 1
  AND (p.privacy IS NULL OR p.privacy = 1 OR (p.privacy = 2 AND fr.fstatus = 1))
ORDER BY n.id DESC
```

Comment: That makes sense, well explained. But my problem lies not in the posts table but the `fr` table. This line `JOIN follows fr ON (n.tonotify_id = fr.tofollow_id)`. Here there may not be `fr.tofollow_id` for all `n.tonotify_id`.

Comment: @user1768337 You need to replace `JOIN` with `LEFT JOIN` for all joined tables where there may be no rows "linked" to `notifications` then.

Comment: Yes I did try `LEFT JOIN follows fr ON (n.tonotify_id = fr.tofollow_id)` but to no avail

Comment: @pewpewlasers If you add `LEFT JOIN` for `fr`, you should also move `fr.user_id = 1` into the `ON` condition.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an outer join such as `LEFT JOIN` instead of an inner join using just `JOIN`. An outer join will always return rows from one "side" (which is why it is called `LEFT [OUTER] JOIN` and `RIGHT [OUTER] JOIN`) even if the other "side" does not match anything.

Comment: I did try it, but the output is the same.