# Simple Join vs. Where Clauses

Tags: mysql, sql

Are the following queries the same? Or are there any major differences (performance)?

```
SELECT 
   u.id, u.username, u.name 
FROM 
   `friends` f, `user` u
WHERE 
   (f.friend_id = u.id AND f.user_id = 2 AND f.fstatus = 1)
```

and

```
SELECT 
   u.id, u.username, u.name 
FROM 
   `friends` f
LEFT JOIN user u ON (f.friend_id = u.id)
WHERE 
   (f.user_id = 2 AND f.fstatus = 1)
```

Comment: The first query has an implicit inner join of friends to user, whereas the second query is using a left outer join of friends to user. Is that your intention?

Comment: You could test them both to determine if there's a performance difference.  The `EXPLAIN` keyword will give you details about the query execution plan.  I *suspect* that the former is more performant than the latter, but it's worth testing to find out.  There may indeed be no appreciable difference, query engines are pretty well optimized.

Comment: The top one is an inner join.

Comment: Oh, I hate the title.  How about "Simple Join vs. Where Clauses"?

Comment: @GordonLinoff okay as you wish :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, technically, these queries are not the same: the first query will not list friends unless there is a corresponding item in the `user` table. Although it shouldn't happen that there is a `friends` row that has no corresponding `user` (that would be a foreign key violation in a relational database with properly defined referential integrity constraints) the theoretical difference remains.

The first query checks the condition `f.friend_id = u.id`, and throws both sides of the join if the condition is not met (i.e. it's an inner join). The second query has an outer join, which is introduced with the `LEFT` keyword. Therefore, the second query will keep the rows of the first table even if there are no corresponding rows in the second table.

Comment: But in this particular example, if the user doesn't have friends, there are no rows to left join right? Which means if no friends, both are empty? But if there is _somehow_ a friends row, second one will output a row, even if there is no corresponding user?

Comment: @user1768337 Ah, I see - it's the other way around (I thought `user` was on the left, not `friend`). I will edit the answer.

Comment: Yup. Thanks for the clarification. Btw I tried to use this same idea in my other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21295910/join-multiple-tables-keeping-nulls but without any progress. If you have some time please do check it out later.